# How to link from browser to Paw.app?

Tags: paw-app

I am using the Paw app for testing API calls to many different endpoints. We have our own admin web app where we can lookup endpoints that I want to test. Now I am copying the URL and pasting it into Paw and then copying the username or API key separately.

It would be awesome if I could add a custom "Open in Paw" link, that prefills the endpoint and auth details. Paw itself uses a "paw://" link for their new serial number registration.

Is it possible to use that schema to do this?

I could not found any documentation on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to use `paw://` schema for the custom link.
It should start with either `paw://current.document/open?` or `paw://new.document/open?`

Then you can choose to open text or URL and give it a url-encoded value like `text=curl%20-X%20%22GET%22%20%22https:%2F%2Fecho.paw.cloud%2F%22%20%5C%09-H%20%22Cookie:%20sessionid%3Dvr3qftico4qeri1l21mayf40axdyidlt%22`

Then choose one of our importers from https://paw.cloud/extensions?extension_type=importer for importing the format of your text/url-resource and include the identifier in the link `&importer=com.luckymarmot.PawExtensions.cURLImporter`

So the full link can look like this `paw://current.document/open?text=curl%20-X%20%22GET%22%20%22https:%2F%2Fecho.paw.cloud%2F%22%20%5C%09-H%20%22Cookie:%20sessionid%3Dvr3qftico4qeri1l21mayf40axdyidlt%22&importer=com.luckymarmot.PawExtensions.cURLImporter`